# Use COPY FROM command in PostgreSQL to insert in multiple tables

Tags: postgresql, database-performance, postgresql-10, sql-tuning

I'm trying to use the performance of `COPY FROM` command in PostgreSQL to get all data of 1 table of a CSV file (CSV -> table1) and I need to insert other data, but, in a new table. I will need of a primary key of first table to put as a foreign key in second table.
Example:
I need to insert 1,000,000 of names in table1 and 500,000 of names in table2, but, all names in table2 reference to 1 tuple in table1.

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
   table1Id bigserial  NOT NULL,
   Name varchar(100)  NULL,
   CONSTRAINT table1Id PRIMARY KEY (table1Id)
);
CREATE TABLE table2 (
   table2Id bigserial  NOT NULL,
   Other_name varchar(100)  NOT NULL
   table1_table1Id int8  NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT table2_pk PRIMARY KEY (table2Id)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Command [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-copy.html) does not allow table manipulations while copying data (such as look up to other table for fetching proper foreign keys to insert). To insert into `table2` ids for corresponding rows from `table1` you need to drop `NOT NULL` constraint for that field, `COPY` data and then `UPDATE` that fields separately.

Assuming `table1` and `table2` tables can be joined by `table1.Name = table2.Other_name`, the code is:

Before COPY:

```
ALTER TABLE table2 ALTER COLUMN table1_table1Id DROP NOT NULL;
```

After COPY:

```
UPDATE table2 SET table2.table1_table1Id = table1.table1Id
FROM table1
WHERE table1.Name = table2.Other_name;
ALTER TABLE table2 ALTER COLUMN table1_table1Id SET NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Hi @Ilya Konyukhov, thanks for the answer. You give me an ideia (create this field with the same value in this two tables and after update). Thanks a lot!